# How to use RL (Robotics Library) with Xcode?

Tags: inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics, manipulator, robotics-library

I came across RL to program robotic manipulators. But according to the website, currently supported websites are Ubuntu and Windows only. Since Ubuntu and Mac OS are based on UNIX kernel, is it possible to deploy RL on MacOS Xcode?

Link : http://www.roboticslibrary.org

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The RL is an open source project, therefore you have access to the source code. The sour code may have references to operating system specific functions and libraries, but offering compatibilitz to linux and windows is a good sign.

I recommend that you download the sourcecode and try to integrate it to a simple XCode project as c++ source code (assuming RL is C++). If it shows a few errors you can try to solve them one by one. If there are too many you should look for a guidance on porting or migrating source code from Win/Linux to XCode.

You can probably get good help on this on StackOverflow. e.g. start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034286/import-existing-c-project-into-xcode-ide) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128646/getting-xcode-to-include-compile-and-link-existing-c-codebase-in-xcode-4-3).

Comment: Than you. I will try that.

Comment: @50k4 can you create and assign the 'robotics-library' tag to this question?
I'm one of the developers of RL and we would like to tell the users to use this tag. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to create tags yet. Thanks!

Comment: @SailAvid Wiki Tag added and approved.

Comment: Nice, many thanks! Can you please also add the tag to this question:
http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10567/is-there-any-c-library-i-could-use-to-program-a-robotic-manipulator-involving

Comment: Done. Also since none of the questions have a accepted answer, please add a detailed answer incl. developer insights